# How to pass a whole message as a single argument in Discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have my Discord bot piece of code here :

```
async def play(ctx, nom_ou_url: str):
    def check_message(message):
        return message.author == ctx.author and message.channel == ctx.channel
    guild = ctx.guild
    if "thomas-carré" in ctx.channel.name:
        choix = mf.get_youtube_url(nom_ou_url)
        print(choix)
```

The role of the **get_youtube_url** function is to look up the top videos on YouTube with **choix** inside the title. My problem is that if **choix** is more than a word, such as "play doh" for example, I have

```
d!play play doh #which only looks up top videos with "play" inside
```

How could I make it so that Discord takes everything after **d!play** as a single argument?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `*` in your argument before `nom_ou_url`.

```py
async def play(ctx, *, nom_ou_url: str):
    def check_message(message):
        return message.author == ctx.author and message.channel == ctx.channel
    guild = ctx.guild
    if "thomas-carré" in ctx.channel.name:
        choix = mf.get_youtube_url(nom_ou_url)
        print(choix)
```